# Can't get SQL JOIN to work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to `JOIN` two tables but it isn't working properly. I have `loc_id` in all tables and they all have a value of `1`. My database is INNODB. `loc_id` is the Unique ID for a third table called `b_locations`. I had tried including this table on `JOIN` as well but I don't really need it and that also gave me the same results. I'd like to be able to `JOIN` 3 or more tables for future proofing, but I need to get 2 working first obviously.

Is my approach of joining on a Unique ID of a table not included in the query a bad approach?

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT d.view_id,
    d.gps_lat survey_lat,
    d.gps_lng survey_lng,
    d.thumbnail,
    c.sign_type,
    c.gps_lat object_lat,
    c.gps_lng object_lng
FROM `d_view_angles` AS d
JOIN c_survey_elements AS c
ON d.loc_id = c.loc_id
WHERE c.loc_id = '1'
```

Here is what I am getting (See **bold** text below desired results):

```
1   37.367156   -77.39987   ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
2   37.367305   -77.399801  ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
3   37.36739    -77.400022  ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
4   37.367619   -77.399897  ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
1   37.367156   -77.39987   ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367408   -77.400077
2   37.367305   -77.399801  ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367408   -77.400077
3   37.36739    -77.400022  ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367408   -77.400077
4   37.367619   -77.399897  ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367408   -77.400077
1   37.367156   -77.39987   ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367635   -77.399944
2   37.367305   -77.399801  ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367635   -77.399944
3   37.36739    -77.400022  ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367635   -77.399944
4   37.367619   -77.399897  ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367635   -77.399944
```

I have tried `GROUP BY survey_lat, survey_lng` but it takes the top 4 results which gives me the following (notice the repeating `c.sign_type`, `c.gps_lat` and `c.gps_lng`):

```
1   37.367156   -77.39987   ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
2   37.367305   -77.399801  ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
3   37.36739    -77.400022  ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
4   37.367619   -77.399897  ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
```

---

**These are the results I should be getting:**

```
1   37.367156   -77.39987   ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
2   37.367305   -77.399801  ... FREESTANDING SIGN   37.367229   -77.399835
3   37.36739    -77.400022  ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367408   -77.400077
4   37.367619   -77.399897  ... DOWN LIGHTING       37.367635   -77.399944
```

I'm sure it is something stupid simple but I haven't been able to track down the issue yet. My guess is my `JOIN`, but I have read numerous tutorials, been all over W3Schools, tried different `JOINS` (`INNER JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, etc) and watched Youtube tutorials. If it is not in my `SQL` statement then recommendations on table formatting are welcome, if any other information is needed just let me know.

---

I have no control over the MYSQL version, this is run off a remote server, hosted by SurpassHosting (I do NOT recommend them).

*MYSQL Server version: 5.0.95-community

Protocol version: 10

Running SQL query through PHPMyAdmin Version information: 3.4.10.1 and MSQL WorkBench 5.2.37 CE*

Comment: Your join is working; unfortunately, you'll probably find that there is more than one row in `c_survey_elements` for each matching id in `d_view_angles` (or vice versa). You therefore have to join on more than one column as your id column may not be unique in `both` tables, or use a filter to eliminate the multiple joins. Posting the structure of both tables (the columns) may help.

Comment: To builld on the previous comment, try showing all the columns from _survey_elements in your query, to see what is unique per row. Then you'll have to use either a filter, or a aggregating function to eliminate them (e.g. MAX, MIN, COUNT), etc.

Comment: Why do you select `... FREESTANDING SIGN` for Id 1, 2 and `... DOWN LIGHTING  ` for id 3, 4??

Comment: the `...` is BLOB data, I just copied and pasted the results from MYSQL WorkBench. There should be two freestanding sign results and 2 down lighting results. The Freestanding sign is one item so the c table lat and lng will be the same but the d table will have different lat and lng. The down lighting is 2 separate elements so it will have unique lat and lng in both tables

Comment: You need to show the contents of your two tables before the join, especially the fields that are joined on.  *(It seems clear that `loc_id` has 4 records in the left table, and 3 records in the right table.  This may mean that you need to use more than just `loc_id` to join on.)*

Comment: Facepalm... I was so focused on Joining on `loc_id` since the data is location specific that I didn't think about Joining on the Unique ID of table `c`. I don't even need a 2nd `JOIN` since my `WHERE` is filtering out other locations. Thanks everyone. Sorry for the n00b question. I should have shown table contents, I think everyone would have come to this result faster. It is working now. @Dems could you please make your comment into an answer so I may mark as accepted.

Comment: @Ben That is a *suggested* link, it is definitely not a *duplicate*. Your target question makes your suggestion little different to a "let me google that for you" answer.

Comment: To think, my entire life I have defined "exact" and "identical" incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems clear that for the same `loc_id` of `1` that there are 4 records in the left table (`d_view_angles`) and 3 records in the right table (`c_survey_elements`).

This may mean that you need to use more than just `loc_id` to join on.

Displaying the relevant contents of each table will make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your table '`d_view_angles` contains multiple register for the loc_id = 1

Check that and be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the unique value is  `d.gps_lng survey_lng,` which is causing more results to be returned, either omit this field from the query or filter your results using `DISTINCT` or `WHERE` otherwise you have the correct query.